# Can you define "| |" to be the same as "Abs[ ]"?

Tags: functions, function-construction, complex

When calculating the modulus of a complex number in Mathematica, the standard (and probably least-ugly) way of doing it is by using the `Abs[ ]` function. When doing it by hand or in LaTeX though, the standard way is to nest the complex number in between vertical bars "| |", like so:

$$\left|3+4i\right|=5$$

Is there a way to do this in Mathematica? That is, is there a way to use "| |" just as we would use `Abs[]` when inputting, and not just formatting the output? I dislike seeing and using a cluster of `Abs[]` functions every time I work with complex numbers.

Comment: You can use TraditionalForm to see it in this form.  *Inputting* it in this form is a different matter though.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yeah I'm interested in inputting it like that. I edited the question.

Comment: Well, you can type ESC l| ESC x ESC r| ESC if you don't find that too tedious.

Comment: Sorry, that's not sufficient.  You also need to define `BracketingBar` to evaluate to `Abs`.